# FindFirstFile and Junctions

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I use this go get the content of directory *foo*: `FindFirstFile(L"foo\\*", &findData)`. It works great when *foo* is a regular directory. However when *foo* is a junction pointing to another directory (created with `mklink /j foo C:\gah`) FindFirstFile fails.

The docs have this to say: "If the path points to a symbolic link, the WIN32_FIND_DATA buffer contains information about the symbolic link, not the target." But when I run it the debugger I just get an `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and findData remains untouched.

So, how do I work around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raymond Chen has an [answer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/12/9962359.aspx) for you.

> Functions like `GetFileAttributes` and `FindFirstFile`, when asked to
>   provide information about a symbolic link, returns information about
>   the link itself and not the link destination. If you use the
>   `FindFirstFile` function, you can tell that you have a symbolic link
>   because the file attributes will have the
>   `FILE_ATTRIBUTES_REPARSE_POINT` flag set, and the `dwReserved0` member
>   will contain the special value `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`.
>
> Okay, great, so now I know I have a symbolic link, but what if I want
>   information about the link target? For example, I want to know the
>   size of the link target, its last-modified time, and its name.
>
> To do this, you open the symbolic link. The I/O manager dereferences
>   the symbolic link and gives you a handle to the link destination. You
>   can then call functions like `GetFileSize`,
>   `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, or `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` to obtain
>   information about the symbolic link target.